# Is the Hallow & Crimson/Corruption "V" random or predetermined?

Tags: terraria

When you enter hard mode your world gets two streaks of Hallow and Crimson or Corruption, depending on what it had before. These generally stripe down at an angle and meet under center of the map but can be offset, apparently controlled a bit by where the Wall of Flesh is defeated.

All of the information I could find said that which side got which biome stripe was random. This however does not seem to be the case from my findings and I could find no information that wasn't already 2-3 years old.

So, is this still random? I am up to 37 resets and the only thing I can change seems to be where the Crimson starts but it is always to the right leaving me nearly no surface Hallow on the left of my map (which is why I am going back to try and reset it.)

To address comment conversations below. I am now up to 58 resets on the same world attempting to get the Hallow and Crimson spawns to swap places on my world. What I am looking for is someone with Terraria v1.3.5.3 to have the same world with both configurations of the hardmode V spawn, hallow on left and right. For testing my world seed is: 1486978588 and is a large world, a [post about the contents of the world may be found here](https://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/share-your-map-seed-pc-1-3-4-beyond.51428/page-7#post-1413579)

Comment: Where are you getting the 2-3 year old information? Not many changes have been made to the game so they may very well still be relevant. Also, it could be both random and predetermined. It's a matter of perspective. On world creation it could be randomly determined. Since you can't change this after the fact it may seem predetermined since you get the same result when resetting after killing the Wall of Flesh.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill Reddit, Steam and the Wiki, dates from 2014 to 2015... They have been doing a bit of reworking with the 1.3 patches and beyond I am just starting to doubt the information out there right now since it feels like it should not be this static if it is random.

Comment: Please add the size of your World. I tested your world seed, and the size changed it considerably, while the choice of corruption/crimson does not seem to matter. Btw, on large size, I got three pyramids!

Comment: @Ranayna World size added along with a link to the Terraria forums where I dumped a full description of the world.. Spoilers abound

Comment: Random and predetermined are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing a similar issue. I had the "perfect" world, with corruption only on the Dungeon side, with the hope to get Hallow on the Jungle side.

But to no avail, everytime I killed the Wall of Flesh, I had always, in at least 40 tries, the corruption spawn on the Jungle side. I tried a lot:

- Different characters
- Different time of day
- Different direction of the Wall

All had the same result.

What I finally did was the following:

- I made a separate backup of the World file, in addition to what Terraria does for itself
- I opened the World in TEdit to get the world seed. My first hope was that i could change it there, but was not able to do that.
- I then opened the .WLD file in Notepad++ (any other Text Editor should do)
- relative at the beginning of the file i saw the World Seed that TEdit showed
- I changed the last digit and saved the file

I was still able to open the World in TEdit, and also in loading it in Terraria still worked with no apparent problems.
I then went about to kill the WoF again, and bingo, I had Hallow on the Jungle side.

Be aware that I give no promises that this will not cause any other ill effects. I will play this world now, and when I see any issues I will edit my post.

Comment: This does kind of imply that the current information online is simply outdated which is my thought as well.. Taking this a step further though to poke the seed and try again however gives us more information.. I think I may give this a try  a few times as well just to confirm seed control over the side selections,

Comment: I just found this wiki page: https://terraria.gamepedia.com/World_Seed. That would explain why it was random in earlier versions of the game if it is dependent on the seed

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hardmode) site, the way the V shaped strips of Hallow and Corruption/Crimson is random, though it will always be a V and at the center of the world.

Comment: Yeah that is what I have found all over the internet but I am now up to 49 attempts an all of them have had the hallow on the left and crimson on the right... i am starting to think something changed, heh... What I am finding equally more frustrating is the common consensus that the hallow normally appears on the right more often.

Comment: Nope. After reading my source again, it doesn't say anything of any changes to this.

Comment: I am starting to wonder about the statistical probability of flipping a coin and getting heads this many times in a row.. Quite a few of their patch notes mention that they do not always list every change.. This question was more a call for information Not coming from these websites and actual game play to see if things had changed from what is on the [Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hardmode), [Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/105600/discussions/0/620695877094426155) or [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Terraria/comments/3beyoy/is_it_predetermined_which_side_the_hallow_spawns/)

Comment: I am not sure of your theory, because I had my Hallow on the right, but I am about to try it.

Comment: Also, with the probability thing, I've had worse luck than that at times on games, since a computer's 50-50 chance is different from flipping a coin.

Comment: Did the fight twice, and got hollow on left once, and hollow right once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62293/discussion-between-james-and-the-mattbat999).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone have this doubt for version 1.4.0.5, I killed WoF twice on the same world just reloading a backup and:

- the side of the evil and hallow stayed the same: hallow to the dungeon, evil to the jungle
- the location of the evil biome stripe moved about 30-40 blocks towards the center of the map
- the hallow biome apparently generated on the same location